# How to use numpy arrays of strings in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, numpy

Numpy's *type strings* (which specify the endianness if applicable, the kind of data, and the amount per item) include a *"String"* option `'S'`, for example, `'|S20'` or `'S20'` represents a fixed-length 20-*char* (in the C sense, i.e., 20 bytes) data type.

Is this *String* (`'S'`) type deprecated?

In python 2 it made sense to use this datatype for arrays of fixed-length python strings. In python 3, this numpy type now corresponds to python *bytes* objects, and an explicit encoding is necessary to translate this to python strings.

Is there any preferred way of storing python 3 strings in numpy arrays? How does the data type length now relate to the number of characters in the string? Does the Unicode-string type `'U'` store a fixed number of characters, or does it vary depending on which characters are stored (i.e. on whether they have short encodings)? Is there a preferred way to convert numpy strings to python strings?

Comment: Unicode is the default string type on Py3.  The `Un` dtype allocates 4 bytes per character.  Make sample array, e.g. `np.array(['one','three'])` and then `view('S1')` to see how the characters are mapped on to the bytes.  Usually though we don't worry about those details.  `pandas` uses `object` dtype, and the native Python strings.

Comment: `arr.tolist()` will produce a list of Python strings.  `numpy` takes care of the conversion (unboxing).

Comment: @hpaulj, `type(np.asarray(['abc','xyz'], dtype='S').tolist()[0])` is `bytes` not `str`. The issue cropped up in code involving a quantity of pickled data, being migrated from python 2 to 3.

Comment: 'S' dtype is bytestring, displayed with `b'abc'` in Py3.   'U' is unicode, the default Py3 string type.  `numpy` `astype` can convert, as can Python `decode/encode`.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, numpy just uses `numpy.str_` to represent its strings as unicode. There is no need for you to worry about this. Just treat all your strings as `str`, since there is really not much of a difference to you. The preferred way to store the strings are in unicode format and the data type length corresponds to the longest string in your array. This length is fixed and so any change to the array will truncate longer strings to that fixed size. numpy will take care of doing all the conversions when necessary.

```
print(type(np.asarray(['abc','xyz'])[0]))
print(type(np.asarray(['abc','xyz']).tolist()[0]))
```

```
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: So by default numpy uses a fixed length string field `<Un`, 4 bytes per encoded character, with the length `n` set by the longest string passed to `np.asarray`. If you then try to reassign a longer string to one of the array elements, it will automatically (and silently) be truncated. To avoid this behaviour it is possible to have an array of (variable-length) python string objects (i.e. pass `dtype='O'` to `np.asarray`), but presumably then most of the numpy performance advantages will be sacrificed.

Comment: Good point. I have updated my answer. And yes, the benefits of numpy having its own type is for performance advantages involving numpy operations. So, using object types would bypass the string truncation but introduce the performance issues. I think the appropriate method to follow would highly depend on your current data and what you are trying to achieve and so is not something that should be generalized.